# Parsing commas in Sphinx

Tags: sphinx

I have a field which can have multiple commas which are actually critical to some regex pattern matching.

Commas however do not index and adding them to the charset breaks it (for a # of technical reasons on how sphinx searches/indexes).

I cannot change the char prior to indexing (e.g. COMMA) so I have some anchor for the pattern and can't properly pattern extract w/o.

My only thought is to use exceptions to map ,=>COMMA (this won't process large text fields so not a huge issue). I'm curious as to if this will work and what the pipeline is i.e. what it could possibly break that I'm not considering. AFAIK Exceptions happen first and do not obey charset so this might in fact work. I get I can test it to see if it does but again I am more concenred with what this might break given my rudimentary knowledge of the pipeline of Sphinx Indexing.

Comment: The prroblem as I continue to explore is neither blend_char or char_set solves my problem; a pattern matching regex looking for ", Word1, Word2".  blend_char will now find ",Word1, Word2" and " Word1, Word2" and "Word1 Word".  char_set will only find "Word1, Word2" (which is what I want) but all of my other pattern searches that were not including commas now fail e.g. if i had a "Word13 NEAR/5 Word4" it will find "Word3 and Word4" but not "Word3, Word4".

Answer (score 0):

> Commas however do not index and adding them to the charset breaks it (for a # of technical reasons on how sphinx searches/indexes).

Just use `U+2C` to add comma to your `charset_table`, e.g.

```
charset_table=a..z,A..Z,0..9,U+2C
```

You might also want to add it to `blend_chars` instead to consider a comma both a word separator and not.

Comment: It breaks things if I add as a character as various stored searches break when the term I'm looking for is followed by a ",". I've tried as Blend_Char assuming will be treated as separator and prior searches that didn't specify "," will work to but so far Blend_Char seems to be having no effect.